# Simple Child Selector not recognized in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, selector, children

I have a simple child selector that is not being recognized in IE9. It happens if I try to use the following "doubleparagraphlink" link:

HTML

```
<div id="block">
    <p><a href="url">Text 1</a></p>
    <p><a href="url">Text 2</a></p>
    <p><a href="url">Text 3</a></p>
    <p><a href="doubleparagraphlink">Text 4.1</p>
    <p>Text 4.2</a></p>
    <p><a href="url">Text 5</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#block > p {
    padding: 0.875em 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    background: cyan;
}
#block > p:first-of-type {
    padding: 0;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Please check the result: http://jsfiddle.net/Jamesss/e5hscL7h/8/

I've been playing with doctype declarations and CSS resets without luck.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You open a link on Text 4.1, then close the paragraph, then open a new paragraph, and then close the link. In other words, your "doubleparagraphlink" link is invalid.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use the same link for both paragraphs. Firefox and Chrome recognize it so I thought it could be used, even if wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to honor the "First In, Last Out" rule.  Your `doubleparagraphlink` `<a>` is breaching its container parent `<p>`.

```
<div id="block">
    <p><a href="url">Text 1</a></p>
    <p><a href="url">Text 2</a></p>
    <p><a href="url">Text 3</a></p>
    <p><a href="doubleparagraphlink">Text 4.1</a></p>
    <p><a href="doubleparagraphlink">Text 4.2</a></p>
    <p><a href="url">Text 5</a></p>
</div>
```

I made the assumption that you simply want both pieces to point to the `doubleparagraphlink`.  This code should work, but is this the functionality you intended?

Comment: Yes, it is, I was about to edit my question regarding this. I'm trying to use the same link for both paragraphs declaring it only once.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend breaking the DOM to achieve this - the rule is there for a reason.  Is there a specific reason why you can't use two?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome recognize it so I thought it could be used, even if wrong. My goal was only to save time, I'll need to update this page very often changing these links.

Comment: If you want to perform this in a way that will be recognized in all major modern browsers, I suggest populating that shared `href` via JavaScript.